Terraform - vRA - fabric network data source
Issue resolved. I am describing below what actions needed for the resource vra_network_ip_range to function properly.
main.tf
data "vra_fabric_network" "rhel" {
  for_each = var.rhel

  **filter = "id eq 'Network_ID'"**
}

resource "vra_network_ip_range" "rhel" {
  for_each = var.rhel

  fabric_network_ids = [data.vra_fabric_network.rhel[each.key].id]
  name               = "xxxxxx"
  description        = "xxxxxx"
  start_ip_address   = xxxxx
  end_ip_address     = xxxxx
  ip_version         = xxxxx
}

To find the appropriate Network id follow the below steps.

login into vRA
Assembler
Infrastructure tab
Resources (in the left side)
Networks (in the left side)
Networks tab
Click on one of the networks which are available there. In the url section after the 2F the remaining is the id of the network.

variables.tf
variable "rhel" {
  type = map(object({
    xxxx = string
    xxxx = string
  }))

  default = {
    range1 = {
      xxxx = "xxxx",
      xxxx = "xxxx"
    },
    range2 = {
      xxxx = "xxx",
      xxxx = "xxx"
    }
  }
}

===============
In the following picture you will see that the New IP Range to be fulfilled and associated with the proper Network ID.
To find the New IP Range which will be created by Terraform follow the below steps.

login into vRA
Assembler
Infrastructure tab
Resources (in the left side)
Networks (in the left side)
IP Ranges tab



I don't know anything about vRA, but you cannot use two different variables for the data source and for the resource in for_each, because the keys will be different. The data.vra_fabric_network.this[each.key].id will not have anything under those keys, since the resource for_each is using local.network_ip_range_map while the data source is using local.network_subnet_map.

@MarkoE
count = length(var.network_ip_range)

@MarkoE Changed it the for_each to the count.
count = length(var.network_ip_range)
Again it did not work. Also change it to have variables like map of objects instead of list of object did not work.
`code
variable "network_ip_range" {
type = list(object({
subnet_name = string
ip = string
network_tag = string
}))
default = [
{
"subnet_name": "xxxxxxxx"
"ip": "xxxxxxx",
"network_tag": "xxxxxx"
}
]
}
`

It's unclear what you have tried. Please add any additional attempts you made to the questions, but make sure it is clear what has changed between different attempts.
